# Divide a dataset while keeping its unbalance

Tags: dataset, preprocessing

I would like to divide a dataset in three part while keeping its unbalance.

For instance let's assume I have a dataset X unbalanced whith 70% majority labels and 30% minority labels.

I would like to get

Y, Z, T with Y + Z + T = X such as Y and Z and T have 70% majority labels and 30 % minority labels.

If anyone can help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

By sampling randomly from the main dataset the percentages from the subsets should roughly equal the percentages from the main dataset. If you however want a more precise way of doing this look into using a stratified method, which allows you to keep class frequencies when splitting/sampling the data. The scikit-learn implementation of the [`train_test_split` function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) provides the `stratify` keyword to automatically split a dataset using stratification.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split (stratify) the data in 2 classes (class A, class B).
2. Then (randomly) split each class in 3 equal parts (33% each).
3. Each Y,Z,T is created by taking one part of class A and one part of class B and making a single dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [code](https://github.com/divijsharma/PythonScripts/blob/master/Data%20Science/Automated%20-%20Train%20-%20Test%20Split.ipynb) that mimics `stratify` of `train_test_split`. [See here](https://github.com/divijsharma/PythonScripts/blob/master/Data%20Science/Automated%20-%20Train%20-%20Test%20Split.ipynb)